# Python Tkinter Class instantiation confusion

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently a novice python student. For fun I decided to try and make a simulation of a led persistence of vision program, however, very early on in my coding I have hit a brick wall. My led class constructor keeps initialising and i do not know why. The code below is somewhat self evident of what i am trying to do. I am trying to generate a strip of leds and set them all to on mode. Yet if you run the following code you will see only the final led is turned on.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

ledboard=tk.Frame(root, height=50, width=1000)
ledboard.pack()

class led(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mode=0
        self._led=tk.Label(ledboard,text="led", padx=20, bg="blue")
        self._led.pack()

    def setmode(self,x):
        self._mode=x
        if self._mode==1:
            self._led.config(bg="red")
        else:
            self._led.config(bg="grey")

    def getmode(self):
        print self._mode

class ledstrip(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._strip=["led1","led2","led3","led4","led5","led6","led7"]
        for i in self._strip:
            self._i=led()

    def getstripmode(self):
        stripmode=[]
        self._strip=["led1","led2","led3","led4","led5","led6","led7"]
        for i in self._strip:
            stripmode.append(self._i.getmode())

    def setstripmode(self, partial):
        self._strip=["led1","led2","led3","led4","led5","led6","led7"]
        for  i in  self._strip:
            self._i.setmode(1)     

x=ledstrip()
x.setstripmode([1,1,1,1,1,1,0])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: my apologies for not being able to properly submit the code here is a codepad link instead http://codepad.org/o7vSeW53

Comment: never mind i realised my error, i hadnt actually instantialised multiple instances of the led, i merely tricked myself into thinkin i had by running the same __init__ over and over.

Comment: Technically speaking you have instantiated multiple led objects, but you haven't stored them anywhere. Alongside of that you don't need to repeat the `self._strip` in every function, because you're declaring that the "functions" are actually methods by sending in the keyword `self` they have access to all instance attributes defined in `__init__` or any other method of that class.